# The norm and the Fourier coefficient if the inner product $\langle f(x), f(x)\rangle$ is negative.

Tags: fourier-series, inner-products, orthogonality

For a real function $f_m(x)$ orthogonal with respect to $w(x)$ where $w(x)>0$. We have inner product
$$
\langle f_m,f_n\rangle_{w}=\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + T}{w(x)f_m(x)f_n(x)dx}
$$
The norm is $||f_m||_{w}=\sqrt{\langle f_m,f_m\rangle_{w}}$, and the Fourier coefficient of function $g(x)$ is $a_m=\frac{\langle g,f_m\rangle_w}{||f_m||_w^2}$.

Here's the question: what if $\langle f_m,f_m\rangle_w<0$? Does the norm $||f_m||=i\sqrt{-\langle f_m,f_m\rangle_w}$ and the Fourier coefficient $a_m=\frac{\langle g,f_m\rangle_w}{||f_m||_w^2}$ still apply?

Thanks!

Comment: $\langle f_m, f_m \rangle$ is never negative for $T>0$, positive weight, and real-valued function $f_m$.

Comment: By definition, if $\langle . , . \rangle$ is an inner product, then $\langle x,x \rangle \geq 0$ for every $x$.

Comment: @pmp For example, let $f_m(x)=cos(m/x)$ with weight function $w(x)=1/x^2$, we have $<f_m,f_m>_w=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+T(x_0)}w(x)[f_m(x)]^2dx=-\pi$, where $T(x)=-x+\frac{x}{(1+2x\pi)}$ is the period.

Comment: It seems in your example $T < 0$, is it?

Comment: By definition, a "periodic function" has some *constant* $p$ such that for all $x, f(x+ p) = f(x)$. Your function $f_m$ is not periodic.